# how to pass a gon value to application.coffee?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using rails gon 
https://github.com/gazay/gon
to get data from controller easy inserted in views
To get an idea (just an example):

```
def show
 gon.alert = "this is an alert"
end
```

now inside my show.haml:

```
:javascript
  alert(gon.alert)
```

Now I always have access to a gon value that i set in controller action before BUT what If you want to access gon values from your application.coffee?

- where to set a gon.current_user = 1 that i can use inside application.coffee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a gon value that you can access from every controller action and thus always available in application.coffee, you can set up a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_gon_values

  private

  def set_gon_values
    gon.current_user = 1  # or whatever you want to set here
  end
end
```

That will run the `set_gon_values` method before every action across all of your controllers.  This works because all of your controllers inherit from `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to the first question: there's nothing special in `application.coffee`, it compiles to javascript anyway. Just make sure that you're accessing `gon.some_variable` in DOM Ready event:

```
$->
  alert gon.alert
```

But then you'll face another problem, how to determine which variable belongs to which controller/action. Moreover, `gon.alert` will be undefined, if you render another controller/action.

So you need to set up a condition in your `application.coffee`, which will be executed only on a specific page (controller/action). For example, you can rely on detecting element ids:

```
$->
  if $('#pages_controller_show').length
    alert gon.alert
```

Your `show.haml` must include an element with `id="pages_controller_show"`, of course.